# How to zip items in 2 lists only when a condition is met - python

Tags: python, arrays, list, zip

When I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['course1', 'course2', 'course3', 'course4', 'course5']
list2 = [12, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

I only want to zip the index list-items together if a condition has met. Otherwise for list index item: 0.

Comment: Zip all, then filter.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What data structure are you zipping them into? I would recommend zipping them all, then removing any (key, value) pairs which don't fulfill the condition.

Comment: *"I only want to zip the index items together when number >= 5.5"* What are index items?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest shorter version using list comprehension:

`[x for x in zip(list1, list2) if x[1] >= 5.5]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a zipped list of lists out of `list1` and `list2` with condition that item of `list2` should be `>=5.5`, then try this :

```
list3 = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(list1, list2) if j>=5.5]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[['course1', 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget zip and create your own solution:

```
list1 = ['course1', 'course2', 'course3', 'course4', 'course5']
list2 = [12, 3, 3, 4, 5]


def zip_condition(list_a, list_b, func):
    iter_a = iter(list_a)
    iter_b = iter(list_b)
    while 1:
        try:
            a, b = next(iter_a), next(iter_b)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        if func((a, b)):
            yield (a, b)


result = list(zip_condition(list1, list2, lambda x: x[1] >= 5.5))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Zipping with `map()`:

```
list1 = ['course1', 'course2', 'course3', 'course4', 'course5']
list2 = [12, 3, 3, 4, 5]

m = map(lambda x, y: (x, y) if y > 5.5 else None, list1, list2)
list(filter(None.__ne__, m))
# [('course1', 12)]
```